# each function INSERT with PHP ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, foreach, each

I am trying to send multiple data with the same `name[]` attribute but I am not able to perform that activity. When I am using this code it not working vey well.
I have also seen other threads but it all was not helpful for me.
Actually data sent to the server in a different structure I seen in the console as I mentioned below.
I wish to insert the data `product` - `qty` wish in PHP for that the structure of sent data should correct -

for eaxample if  - product `123456` `QTY` = `2500` AND If product `452136` `QTY` will = `100`.

Please help me, How I make this function with this data in PHP.

full code is -

```js
$("form").unbind("submit").bind("submit", function(event) {
      var qty = [];
      $('input[name="quantity[]"]').each(function() {
        qty.push(this.value);
      });
      var product = [];
      $('input[name="product[]"]').each(function() {
        product.push(this.value);
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: "_URL_",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          qty: qty,
          pro: product
        },
        cache: false,

        success: function(response) {
          alert("OK");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("Not Ok");
          return false;
        }
      });

//SENDING DATA STRUCTURE in CONSOLE
 
product[]: 123456
product[]: 452136
qty[]: 2500
qty[]: 100

// ARRAY STRUCTURE IN PHP
[product] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123456
        [1] => 452136
    )

[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2500
        [1] => 100
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. I think problem lies elsewhere. Try to `console.log($('input[name="product[]"]').length)` to see if your jquery selector grabs right inputs.

```js
let product = [];
$('input[name="product[]"]').each(function() {
  product.push(this.value);
});
console.log(product);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="product[]" value="1">
  <input name="product[]" value="2">
  <input name="product[]" value="3">
```

---

**Answer on UPDATE**

If you wish to send associative array of product, you should use this name structure

```
<input name="product[id]" value="123456">
<input name="product[qty]" vlaue="2500">
```

then you will get result in php in this format

```
'products' => [
  [
    'id' => 123456,
    'qty' => 2500
  ],
  [
    'id' => 452136,
    'qty' => 100
  ]
]
```

Comment: I updatec the question.. actually Pls help